# Samba/CIFS permissions (server Debian 10, client Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: permissions, samba, cifs

As in the subject:  samba server running on a Debian 10 machine (inside my home LAN, 192.168.1.x); client is my PC, running Ubuntu 22.04

(1) Files on my PC show with permission 644, regardless of the permission of the file on the server's filesystem.

(2) Running `chmod` on my PC has no effect (when applied to the files on the CIFS-mounted directories, that is).

(3) Running `chmod` on the server affects the permissions on the server, but (1) still applies, so I can never have an executable on an Samba/CIFS filesystem.

This is the configuration for one of the Samba shares exhibiting this problem:

```
[schoolwork]
path = /data-RAID1/schoolwork
available = yes
browsable = no
public = no
writable = yes
write list = cal
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
```

On my PC, the `/etc/fstab` entry is as follows:

```
//192.168.1.2/schoolwork  /remote/schoolwork cifs defaults,credentials=/etc/cifs/credentials.txt,uid=cal,gid=cal,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 0 0
```

If I add `cifsacl` to the mount options in the `/etc/fstab` line, that (sort of) fixes the problem, but now permissions seem to be oddly restricted: if I do `chmod 644`, permissions are changed to 666; `chmod 755` changes to 777; however, `chmod 600` changes to `-rwx-----T` (not sure why that sticky bit `T` appears)

I guess I can live with that, but is there a way to maintain the native Unix/Linux style permissions?